# Heapq module implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, heap, standard-library

I was reading the `heapq` module source because I reviewed a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/208706/87312) on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and I cannot understand something.

In the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Operations) about heap it says:

> sift-up: move a node up in the tree, as long as needed; used to restore heap condition after insertion. Called "sift" because node moves up the tree until it reaches the correct level, as in a sieve.
>
> sift-down: move a node down in the tree, similar to sift-up; used to restore heap condition after deletion or replacement.

But the code of `heappush` ([source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/heapq.py#L130)) is :

```
def heappush(heap, item):
    """Push item onto heap, maintaining the heap invariant."""
    heap.append(item)
    _siftdown(heap, 0, len(heap)-1)
```

If I read wikipedia right, when inserting an element I was expecting to see a `siftup` call, not a `siftdown` one.

Similarly for `heappop` ([source here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/heapq.py#L135)):

```
def heappop(heap):
    """Pop the smallest item off the heap, maintaining the heap invariant."""
    lastelt = heap.pop()    # raises appropriate IndexError if heap is empty
    if heap:
        returnitem = heap[0]
        heap[0] = lastelt
        _siftup(heap, 0)
        return returnitem
return lastelt
```

From the wikipedia article I was expecting a `siftdown` call but got a `siftup` one.

Is it a mistake in Wikipedia or on the `heapq` module? Or is my understand wrong?

Comment: It makes sense that you need to sift up after a pop.  After all, you're removed the top element of the heap.  Something has to move up the tree to take its place.

Comment: Then wikipedia is wrong in this case?

Comment: I don't see what you think is wrong with Wikipedia.  It says that "sift-up" sifts a node up the tree.  And that's exactly what you need to do when you pop.

Comment: Oh I see: "sift-down: used to restore heap condition after deletion or replacement" but `heappop()` calls it `_siftup()`.  In this case I think Wikipedia's naming is actually more standard.

Comment: This has just to do with visualisation. Usually the heap is imagined with the root at the top, and then the language of Wikipedia makes sense, but there is no reason why the heap could not be imagined with the root at the bottom. I mean: real-life trees have their roots in the soil, not in the sky. ;-)

Comment: Another reason to use the opposite wording, is that it corresponds with how index values are greater/lesser in the array implementation of a heap. Sifting up is then towards greater indexes.

Comment: @trincot There is also an ambiguity in what you consider is getting sifted.  If you start with an element at the root (which you visualize at the top) and push it down, you have to push one of its children up.  So something is moving in each direction.

Comment: Indeed, that is yet another consideration.

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanations, Now I need to go on the whiteboard to help me visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, it's a nomenclature issue. The most common terminology calls the root the "top" of the tree, and nodes at other levels are "below" the root. We draw the tree in that orientation. That is:

```
        1
    2       3
  4   5   6   7
```

It makes sense, then, to say that to move an item from the root to a lower level is "sifting down."

You could make the argument, as somebody did in comments, that moving something to a lower level is increasing its index in the backing array, so it makes sense to speak of that as "sifting up". But people are visualizing the tree model, not the array implementation. When speaking of the model, your terminology should be consistent with the model.

I've always found it a bit annoying that the author of `heapq` decided to use the non-standard terminology. One could argue that he's talking about the implementation, but I dispute that. The comment says, "sift-up: move a node up in the tree ..." Clearly, he's referring to the tree *model*.

Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure, says:

> A tree structure or tree diagram is a way of representing the hierarchical nature of a structure in a graphical form. It is named a "tree structure" because the classic representation resembles a tree, even though the chart is generally upside down compared to an actual tree, with the "root" at the top and the "leaves" at the bottom.

This topic was discussed to death in the early days, perhaps most famously by Donald Knuth in *The Art of Computer Programming*. See https://www.quora.com/Why-are-trees-in-computer-science-generally-drawn-upside-down-from-how-trees-are-in-real-life.

Comment: Great link for explaining why tree are upside down, good answer!