# how to build maxHeap in python

Tags: python

Just check the perkDown method . it shows index out of range error .. I don't know why i am getting that error over and over again .

```
[42, 29, 18, 14, 7, 18, 12, 11, 5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled ", line 62, in <module>
    b.dilMax()
  File "Untitled ", line 48, in dilMax
    self.perkDown(1)
  File "Untitled ", line 37, in perkDown
    max_child = self.getMaxChild(i)
  File "Untitled ", line 31, in getMaxChild
    if self.heap[i*2] > self.heap[i*2+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range**
```

```
class BinaryHeap:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self . heap = [0]
        self. size = 0
    
    def swapUp(self, i):
        
        while i // 2 > 0 :
            if self.heap[i] > self.heap[i//2]:
                self.heap[i], self.heap[i//2] = self.heap[i//2], self.heap[i]
            i = i//2
            
    
    def insert(self , value):
        # add
        self.heap.append(value)
        self.size += 1
        #maintain
        self.swapUp(self.size)
        
    def getMaxChild(self, i):
        if i * 2 > self.size:
            return i * 2
        else:
            if self.heap[i*2] > self.heap[i*2+1]:
                return i * 2
            return i * 2 + 1
    
    def perkDown(self, i):
        while i * 2 <= self.size:
            max_child = self.getMaxChild(i)
            if self.heap[i] < self.heap[max_child]:
                self.heap[i], self.heap[max_child] = self.heap[max_child], self.heap[i]
            i = max_child
    
    def dilMax(self):
        ret_val = self.heap[1]
        self.heap[1]  = self.heap[self.size]
        self.size -= 1
        self.heap.pop()
        # maintain the heap 
        self.perkDown(1)
        
    
b = BinaryHeap()
b.insert(42)
b.insert(29)
b.insert(18)
b.insert(14)
b.insert(7)
b.insert(18)
b.insert(12)
b.insert(11)
b.insert(5)
print(b.heap[1:])
b.dilMax()
print(b.heap[1:]
```

Comment: when `i*2` equals `self.size`, `i*2+1` is out of range

Comment: Can you explain me ??

Comment: What is unclear ? if `i=4` and `size=8`, you can access data `2*4` which is 8, but `2*4=1` is 9 so there is no data at this index, you're out of range

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `i * 2 >= self.size`. That's what causes the error. Because  when `i * 2 == self.size`, `self.heap[i*2+1]` is out of bounds.

```
def getMaxChild(self, i):
        if i * 2 >= self.size:
            return i * 2
        else:
            if self.heap[i*2] > self.heap[i*2+1]:
                return i * 2
            return i * 2 + 1
```

Also, I see that you had to explicitly print `b.heap[1:]`. A better solution would be to override the `__str__()` method.
Add this method to your `BinaryHeap` class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.heap[1:])
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [max/min heap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) already implemented in python:

```py
In [1]: import heapq
   ...:
   ...: h = []
   ...: heapq.heappush(h, 1)
   ...: heapq.heappush(h, 10)
   ...: heapq.heappush(h, 3)
   ...: heapq.heappush(h, 2)

In [2]: h
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 10]

In [3]: h[-2:]
Out[3]: [3, 10]

In [4]: h[::-1]
Out[4]: [10, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you really wish to implement your own version, maybe you can have a look at [this discussion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197040/min-max-heap-implementation-in-python). There's also another question about the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546052/heapq-module-implementation). And yet another about complexity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55373969/1720199).